# Сложный Чпу

Tags: php, чпу

Привет всем, возник вопрос. Фильтр посылает GET запрос в зависимости выбран ли элемент. Есть 3 варианта => version maps tank. Если выбрана версия соответственно /version/4/ (так же maps и tank). Если выбрана и версия и карта, то /version/4/maps/5,5/. Ну и если выбрано всё то /version/5/maps/8/tank/34/.

Собственно никак не получается сделать такой динамический чпу. Помогите, пожалуйста, или скиньте ссылки на примеры.

Comment: Вам регулярное выражение надо?

    /version/4/maps/5,5/

Что значит через запятую `5,5`?

И можете вы подробнее объяснить "так же maps и tank":

    если выбрана версия соответственно /version/4/ (так же maps и tank)

Comment: версий может быть несколько например version/5,7,5/
также как и карт и танков
и числа меняются в зависимости от выбранных чекбоксов

Comment: Может, так?

    version\/([0-9,]+)(\/maps\/([0-9,]+)(\/tank\/([0-9,]+))?)?\/?

пропускает:

version/5
version/5,4
version/5,4/maps/1
version/5,4/maps/1,2
version/5,4/maps/1,2/tank/5
version/5,4/maps/1,2/tank/5,6

Comment: получается так?
RewriteRule ^search2/version\/([0-9,]+)(\/maps\/([0-9,]+)(\/tank\/([0-9,]+))?)?\/? search2.php?version=$1&maps=$2&tank=$3

тогда

/version/7/tank/4101/
версию выводит и танк нет

Comment: Подправьте немного :)

    version\/[0-9,]+(\/maps\/([0-9,]+))?(\/tank\/([0-9,]+))?/?

или так (будет принимать в любом порядке):

    ((\/?version\/[0-9,]+)?|(\/maps\/([0-9,]+))?|(\/tank\/([0-9,]+))?)+

  1. /version/5,4/maps/1,2/tank/5,6
  2. /tank/5,4/maps/1,2/version/5,6
  3. /maps/5,4/tank/1,2/version/5,6

Answer (score 1):

Регулярка тут обязывает последовательность параметров жёсткую.
Я бы сделал так.
Из переменной $_SERVER взял строку с параметрами:

```
$args = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; // Точно не помню, но вроде так :)
```

Пилим её по слешам:

```
$args = explode('/', $args);
```

Собираем в массив, чётные ключи, нечетные - значения:

```
    $params = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($args); $i = $i + 2){
        $params[$args[$i]] = $args[$i + 1];
    }
```

И валидатор очень удобно написать: кол-во элементов после exclude четное - значит всё ок.

Comment: Вы глубоко заблуждаетесь. QUERY_STRING содержит в себе параметры GET запроса, т.е. все то, что идет после ?:

    http://google.com?hello=world

В этом случае в QUERY_STRING будет `hello=wolrd`, а в нужном автору url параметров нету, собственно поэтому в теме и фигурирует "ЧПУ" (а QUERY_STRING в его случае будет пустой строкой).

Чем обосновано ваше заявление о том, что регулярное выражение обязывает жесткую последовательность параметров? К примеру, это:

    ((\/version\/[0-9,]+)?|(\/maps\/([0-9,]+))?|(\/tank\/([0-9,]+))?)+

Comment: @likerRr почему бы тогда не универсализировать?
    (\/[^/]\/[0-9,]+)+
Добавите новый параметр в форму и будете регулярки править?

Comment: @dimka3210, Вы при валидации числовых полей тоже универсализируете /^(.*)$/ или уточняете /^\d+$/? 

В общем случае пишется роутер, которому подается человеко понятная запись предварительного регулярного выражения с правилами для параметров, например:

    /(tasks/<tasksIds>/)(maps/<mapsIds>/)(tank/<tanksIds>)

    array(
        'tasksIds' => '[0-9,]+',
        ...
    );


Затем роутер формирует из него регулярку, поэтому сложностей с добавлением новых полей не возникает. Формирование динамических ЧПУ это и есть набор регулярных выражений, загляните в любой роутер любого PHP фреймворка